# NodeJS/Mongoose - Combining then accessing collections

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a field called 'allGroups' under my Blogs schema which combines all the options from 3 different models (Community, Business and Help) and allows the user to select multiple options from a dropdown list and store their ID in an array.

```
   allGroups: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Community" 
      },
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Business"
      },
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Help" 
      }
   ],
```

This is correctly saving the id of the respective option to the database; however, when I try to retrieve the name of each in my .EJS template using a forEach loop, I'm only able to return group._id, whereas I also want to return group.name (all individual models have the 'name' field).  So my first question is, do I need to add something else in my model for the allGroups field to be able to access group.name, or is there another way I can access?

```
<% blog.allGroups.forEach((group) => { %>
    <div><%- group._id %> <%- group.name %></div>
<% }) %>
```

Second question: As well as returning group.name, I also want to link to the respective records, which requires me to access their original models.  Below is some mock code as an example; how can I reference the original model that each record belongs to so I can return the correct link prefix for each? I'm aware of Mongoose' 'instanceof' method, but I've only managed to get this to work in my controller, I'm unsure if it's possible to use within my .EJS template directly?  Or is there another/better way to do this? Thanks.

```
<% blog.allGroups.forEach((group) => { %>
    <% if (Original Model === "Business") { %>
        <a href="/business/<%- group._id %>"><div><%- group.name %></div></a>
    <% else if (Original Model === "Help") { %>
        <a href="/help/<%- group._id %>"><div><%- group.name %></div></a>
    <% else if (Original Model === "Community") { %>
        <a href="/community/<%- group._id %>"><div><%- group.name %></div></a>
    <% } %>
<% }) %>
```

Current controller for reference:

```
    async blogShow (req, res, next) {
        let blog = await blog.findById(req.params.id).populate('interviewees allGroups likes').populate({
            path: "comments",
            model: "Comment",
            options: { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}
        });

        res.render("blogViews/showBlog", { blog, cloudinary });
    },
```

Comment: You need to use `populate` to retrieve the group details ,can you add the router which render this template?

Comment: Thanks, just added to my original answer.  I have populated allGroups how and that seems to be in the right direction as i can now access the name; HOWEVER, it is only returning the values from the first collection in allGroups - Community - and it not returning the values from Business and Help

Comment: You have to render the ejs file  here `res.render("blogViews/showKnowPangyao"` it should be something like `blog.ejs` or `blog` :the name of the ejs file. and knowPangyao,  also her you have to pass the results returned by query that is `blog ` not `{knowPangyao, cloudinary }`

Comment: it should be like this     `res.render("blogViews,ejs", { blog:blog });` @Martin

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the ejs file here res.render("blogViews/showKnowPangyao" it should be something like `blog.ejs` or `blog`:the name of the ejs file, and in place of `knowPangyao`you have to pass the results returned by query that is blog  not {knowPangyao, cloudinary } it should be  `{ blog:blog }`.
TRY:

```
 async blogShow (req, res, next) {
        let blog = await blog.findById(req.params.id).populate('interviewees allGroups likes').populate({
            path: "comments",
            model: "Comment",
            options: { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}
        });

        res.render("blogViews.ejs", { blog:blog });
    },
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck I'm afraid, still only returning the first record

Comment: Sorry ignore the knowPangyao, that was a copy/paste error, I've updated it.  There is no issue with rendering the file (I have numerous different collections hence why they are grouped into different views.  The issue is with the population; it is only returning the first record from the Community group, and nothing else (in the example I'm trying there should be one community, one help and one business).

Comment: I have searched a lot but i can't find a way for the type of schema of `allGroups` .Acc. to to you it is only populatting community .It seems that in an array we can only populate one path , But there must be some way to do it

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, yes I still feel their should be a way given that it allows you to combine the records in the first place, surely you should be able to access the underlying models.